# Xna Spritefont from installed fonts

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, fonts, visual-studio, spritefont

I am using Spritefont in my game and I have downloaded a .ttf font and installed it on my machine. I am now using this font in my game.

My question is if this game is run on another machine will the .ttf font need to be installed on that machine to work?

Comment: You can also use tools like SpriteFont2 to render it to a texture at a fixed size. Either way, be VERY careful regarding licensing restrictions on the font - just having access to the file doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a font is located in the content folder, and you keep the content folder along with your game, then it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Spritefonts are treated similair like images, They both remain in the contents folder.

I've used a downloadable spritefont before and I could use it on different computers without any problems. I think it's a bit depending on how you're releasing your game. (I've used the release folder after building the game in the release configuration)

I think the best way is to try it out yourself, by putting the game and the content folder on someone else's PC. :)